# .NET 4.6 HttpResponse.PushPromise methods to manage http/2 PUSH_PROMISE header

Tags: c#, http2, .net-4.6, push-promise

I am a bit confused about [PUSH PROMISE](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PUSH_PROMISE) [http/2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.pushpromise(v=vs.110).aspx) header handling in `.NET4.6`.

[When I look](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.pushpromise(v=vs.110).aspx) `HttpResponse.PushPromise` there are two overloads:

[One that accepts path to resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823329(v=vs.110).aspx) `public void PushPromise(string path)` -  am assuming resource is then read and binary sent across to client.

[Second](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823340(v=vs.110).aspx) `public void PushPromise(string path, string method, NameValueCollection headers)` that accepts `sting method` and `NameValueCollection headers` which I am failing to understand.

**Why would I want to pass method (assuming HttpMethod like GET, POST, etc) and collection of headers inside `PUSH PROMISE` header?**

Comment: the MS documentation really is appauling for this! not even a code example

Comment: their is better documentation in the sourcecode itself https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HttpResponse.cs (search for 'PushPromise')

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Thanks Simon, much appreciated.

Comment: *THERE* is bettter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the HTTP/2 [spec (Section 8.2)](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.8.2), here is what I gather:

#### Passing the method

`PUSH_PROMISE` frames are required to be *cacheable* and *safe*. You have the option of using `GET` and `HEAD`, as those are the only two http methods that are defined as both safe and cacheable.

#### Passing headers

Since `PUSH_PROMISE` frames are required to be cacheable, this could be used to add specific `Cache-Control` directives to the promise. [Section 8.2.2 of the spec](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#rfc.section.8.2.2) states that a client has the option to download the promised stream and can refuse it, which I imagine a client would do if it found that it had an up-to-date version of the resource in its cache.

Controlling caching is the most obvious reason I can see for why you might pass headers, but there may be other reasons as well. If you're writing a custom client, you may use certain X-Headers to provide other hints (that aren't related to caching) to the client so it can decide whether or not it wants to accept the promised stream.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass headers for anything that will cause your response to vary (i.e. anything in your Vary response header). The biggest one I've found is compression.

Read those headers from the original client request and include them with your push promise, e.g.:

```
var headers = new NameValueCollection { { "accept-encoding", this.Request.Headers["accept-encoding"] } };
this.Response.PushPromise("~/Scripts/jquery.js", "GET", headers);`
```

Comment: I'm not convinced about this. I think you would add a header here only if the **contents** of the file would vary based on that particular header. The content of the uncompressed file never changes so this does nothing useful. I think the need for specifying `headers` is a very specialized case that most people need not worry about. Perhaps if the *content* of the file varied based on the browser's language then you would use this, but obviously `jquery.js` is a static file here so the content doesn't change. If the file was dynamic based on language you could use it.